# Python/Boto + AWS S3 versioning: how do I replace the current key with older version?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning, boto

Using python/boto to interface with AWS S3 on a bucket with versions enabled - how do you revert a key to a historical version?

I can download the historical version of the file and re-upload it, but this is inefficient and causes a duplicate key.  Is there a way to pick the version that I want and make it active/current, (such that it's downloaded automatically when the version is not supplied)?

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.create_bucket('my_test_bucket')
key = Key(bucket)
key.key = 'my_file.pdf'
key.set_contents_from_filename('1.pdf')
key.set_contents_from_filename('2.pdf')
key.set_contents_from_filename('3.pdf')

# Now I have a file with the key `my_file.pdf`
# and I can see the versions using something like:
versions = list(bucket.list_versions('my_file.pdf'))
print [k.version_id for k in versions]

# To make on older version active, I can download & re-upload
versions[1].get_contents_to_filename('old.pdf')
key.set_contents_from_filename('old.pdf')

# But this seems very inefficient, and creates duplicate version keys.  It would be
# Nice to do something like:
versions[1].last_modified = datetime.now()
# Or even this, but this seems less efficient:
versions[1].copy('my_test_bucket', 'my_file.pdf')  # And then delete 
bucket.delete_key('my_file.pdf', version_id=versions[1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot "move" a version to be the "current" version, but you can use `copy_key()` to copy a previous version to the same key, thereby making it the 'current' version.

```
> versions = list(bucket.list_versions('my_file.pdf'))
> print [k.version_id for k in versions]
[u'tsbfD0oKQ87a.cWyImABs5lVhVv84dnC', u'0nKieCek8C4q4GegjXKh8UhJCoiAMrqM', u'null']
> key.name
'my_file.pdf'
> bucket.copy_key(key.name, 'bucket-name', key.name, src_version_id=u'0nKieCek8C4q4GegjXKh8UhJCoiAMrqM')
```

This results in a new version, which is a copy of the earlier version. All copying is done "within" S3, without needing to download/upload the contents.

Yes, it still creates another version. If this is undesired, you can then delete the previous version:

```
bucket.delete_key(key.name,version_id=u'0nKieCek8C4q4GegjXKh8UhJCoiAMrqM')
```